# I don't get intellisense when using require

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I'm using nodejs, typescript, electron, and react to build an application. My problem started when I tried to import mongodb like normal, however, it said some dependencies were not installed, so I required it instead. When Using require, I get no intellisense at all. Some nodejs packages are able to be imported and work fine while others don't. Does anyone have a solution to this problem. I can provide code if needed.

Errors when using import with mongo db(this behavior continues with different packages after I install kerberos):

```
Error: Could not resolve "kerberos" imported by "mongodb". Is it installed?
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/brodieliverman/Documents/GitHub/LC-Mod-Manager/electron-vite-project/dist-electron/main.js:13925:7)
```

Comment: `npm install kerberos` see [`peerDependencies`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/package.json#L32)

Comment: @Konrad do I just install all the peer dependencies? Do I have to add anything more specific to any of the config files?